# Android specific code not running on Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I've just started to use Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0 to build a cross platform app.

Using VS Community 2017.

When I create a new project, make no changes to the template code that is generated and build it I get no errors as expected. Also when I debug it the initial template code runs fine on my android phone. However the OnCreate method in the template MainActivity method in the Android project is not being called. I know this because no breakpoints are hit in it and if I alter the code it makes no difference to the output. The constructor in App.xaml.cs is being called and breakpoints are being hit there just fine.

There are some changes which I would like to make to the Android project but I can't since they are not being detected when I debug. Cleaning and rebuilding the solution doesn't fix it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I will not run, if the `MainActivity` is not called. Is the project building correctly? Do you have another activity that may be called as an entry activity? Are you really debugging?

Comment: That's the thing that confuses me. I am literally not changing the Xamarin.Forms cross platform app template and it builds fine. The PCL code is definitely running and debugging etc. on an Android phone, but the Android project code is not running. The MainActivity class in the Android project is not being called (even though it has the MainLauncher = true activity tag set). When I look at the AndroidManifest.xml that's generated in the debug folder I can see that it has created the correct Activity tags to set this as the Main Launcher activity however it is definitely not running this code.